# Packaging python with circular imports

Tags: python, import, namespaces

I looked through previous questions to this effect, but my situation is slightly different...

I've got a directory that contains several python classes that import one another here and there where necessary.  I'd like to start packaging them up into smaller modules, mostly for purposes of organization.  The central component of the package sets up a wsgi application and then additional modules provide functionality to it (this has worked great so far since I can test the mods individually on the command line before hooking their inputs up to the web app.)

I understand how supplying an `__init__.py` module works, its namespacing, and when it releases control.  What I am having trouble with is that the modules in certain cases import one another.

For example, I have a JSONEncoder that is used as the `cls` argument for many calls to `json.dumps()`  This class is used in virtually every file.  If I move some of these modules to subdirectories within the package, how would I go "up one level" to import the json encoder?  Would I need to put the parent directory on the PYTHONPATH in every file?  Would it be better to give the encoder its own directory as well, with a separate __init__.py file?

Alternatively, would I just be better off putting in a function that drills down through all directories below the current working dir and adds them to the path?

Currently the main directory that contains all the code is not package in of itself... what would be the best approach to migrating like classes to subdirectories taking into account that they have circular imports?

**EDIT:**

For clarification:

The main working directory I've been developing is just a regular directory containing about ten .py files, all of which contain classes with names like their filenames.  Currently the whole thing is just a git repo of .py files.

```
-project
  search.py
  jsonencoder.py
  webapp.py
  modela.py
  modelb.py
  modelc.py
```

Names are of course for example purposes.

Now as I understand it (which could be totally wrong) the sensible thing to do would be to package those models together, correct?

```
-project
  search.py
  jsonencoder.py
  webapp.py
  -models
    __init__.py
    modela.py
    modelb.py
    modelc.py
```

But then in turn, would the `project` folder need an `__init__` too?  How would modela, which uses jsonencoder, import it?

Comment: "I've got a directory that contains several python classes".  That's not sensible.  Directories contain files.  Directories may also be Python packages.  Files are modules.  Modules contain class definitions.  Can you clarify your question please?

Comment: @S.Lott Edited with an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is quite simple:

just use the fully qualified name for the sub-module you need

For example, under

```
mybundle/test/__init__.py
```

you can have the line

```
import mybundle.JSONEncoder
```

- it will do just the right thing.

For example, given this module structure:

```
├── mybundle
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── jsonencoder
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   └── test
│       ├── __init__.py
```

with the files defined as in:

```
[gwidion@powerpuff tmp]$ cat mybundle/__init__.py
import test

[gwidion@powerpuff tmp]$ cat mybundle/test/__init__.py
import mybundle.jsonencoder

[gwidion@powerpuff tmp]$ cat mybundle/jsonencoder/__init__.py
print 5
```

This works:

```
[gwidion@powerpuff tmp]$ python
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Apr 12 2011, 16:15:16) 
[GCC 4.6.0 20110331 (Red Hat 4.6.0-2)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import mybundle
5
>>>
```

Comment: So then the critical thing is to have an __init__.py in the root as well, which will bubble to the submodules and execute their init scripts as well.  How does the init within the test subdirectory know where mybundle is?

Comment: Yes, having an `__init__.py` on the root is critical - it can be empty (0 bytes) though. Creating an empty `__init__.py` makes Python treat the directory as a module, and other directories containing `__init__.py` files as submodules of that. From then on, using import <module>.<submodule> just works, if <module> can be found by the application in anyway. (and <module> is just the name of your root directory)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this (`root` is your working directory):

```
/root
  - file_a.py
  - file_b.py
  /JSONEncoder 
    - __init__.py
    - JSONEncoder.py
```

`__init__.py` is blank, or has `pass` or a comment or something. 
You can then do (from `file_a.py` or whatever in `root`):

```
from JSONEncoder import JSONEncoder
```

and have access to `JSONEncoder` in `file_a.py`. You don't need to touch `PYTHONPATH` as long as all your running code resides in `/root` and `__init__.py` is only needed in the subdirs. This type of directory layout is very useful as you can hide away code that 'just works' and focus on the code that you need to work on.